# Cronjob doesn't run on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-compute-engine

I set up a cron job in a instance on Google Cloud's compute engine.

It is suppose to run at 7:47am every day. However each time I check if the file has been executed at 7:48 it does not work.

[image]

The code for the helloworld.sh file is here

```
echo "helloworld" + "$(date)" > helloworld.txt
```

I have set checked as root and set up the cron job as root still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron job is wrong because you need to use absolute paths in your command. Try:

```
/bin/bash /home/username/helloworld.sh
```

Comment: Still have a problem. I checked cron status and it is active.

Comment: I am facing the same. `service crond status` gives `Unit crond.service could not be found.` even after a `sudo service cron  start`

Comment: @mathiasrw, The command you'll need to check the service status is: ```service cron status```. If you refer, to the service as: **crond**, the service will not be found.